# Open or closed in relative metric

Tags: general-topology

$C=(1/4, 3/4)$, is $C$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I think it is open by definition of open. But I am not sure what is the difference between $C$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $C$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What is your definition of open in $\Bbb R^2$? Does $C$ satisfy that definition?

Answer (score 1):

The real interval $C:=\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right)$ is *not* open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it *is* open in $\mathbb{R}$. Recall that a set $S$ is open if for every point $p$ in it you can construct an open ball centered at $p$ and contained in $S$. A ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a disk, and since in this case $C$ is a line, it has no width and thus for no point of it can you find a disk centered at the point and contained in it. Note that a ball in $\mathbb{R}$ is a line segment.